# Enormous and weird error in scikit-learn in Python Logistic Regression?

Tags: python, pandas, regression, shapes

Below operations concern Logistic Regression in Python scikit-learn

I give you the most important sample of the code:

```
predictions = logistic_regression.predict(X_test)
prediction=logistic_regression.predict_proba(X_test)[:,:]
prediction=pd.DataFrame(data=predictions, 
                         columns=['Prob of Bad credit (0)','Prob of Good credit (1)'])
prediction.head(10)
```

And yesterday I had result of this code which was in line with my expectations:
(not the same table title but the same result)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdqeR.png)

But today, I absolute do not have idea why, when I wanted to run this code again I have an Error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (300, 1), indices imply (300, 2)
```

How it is possible that yesterday it worked and today not ? What can I do ? 
Screen of full error below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnrJY.png)

sample of predictions is like that:

```
print(predictions)
```

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1]

and I do not want to have 1 or 0 in table I would like to have in percent probaility of 1 or 0 as in example in screen

Look at the same table at the end of prediction from below source, there is the same code and it works: 
https://www.kaggle.com/neisha/heart-disease-prediction-using-logistic-regression

Comment: Probably because the first value is being taken as index? And the second as the first column, therefore you are missing data for the second column?

Comment: It'd be a good idea *not* to name your variables so similarly. Are you sure `data=predictions` is using the variable you wanted?

Comment: Also, why are you using `[:,:]` after the predictions?

Comment: `predict()` gives you the predicted class (single column of data), `predict_proba` gives you tuples of predicted class probabilities. You're saying there are two columns in your dataframe call. Echoing @user2357112supportsMonica, check your variables

Comment: but yesterday it worked, how it is possible and how can I edit my code ?

Comment: `prediction=pd.DataFrame(data=predictions, `change this line to `prediction=pd.DataFrame(data=prediction, `. Notice the s change after `data` on prediction.

Comment: wow I do not belie it that this is only 1 mark, your are a master! It works, THANK YOU GUYS !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error occurs because prediction has just one row,
and you have two column names:

```
prediction=pd.DataFrame(data=predictions, 
                         columns=['Prob of Bad credit (0)','Prob of Good credit (1)'])
```

Based on the codes on kaggle you provide:

```
y_pred_prob=logreg.predict_proba(x_test)[:,:]
y_pred_prob_df=pd.DataFrame(data=y_pred_prob, columns=['Prob of no heart disease (0)','Prob of Heart Disease (1)'])
y_pred_prob_df.head()
```

I think you should change your code to:

```
prediction_df = pd.DataFrame(data=prediction,  
                         columns=['Prob of Bad credit (0)','Prob of Good credit (1)'])
```

Be careful it should be prediction, not predictions.

Comment: it also does not work, now I have and error : ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 300), indices imply (2, 2)

Comment: you have defined prediction before which is a 2 by 2 array. try to set another name  and it should work

Comment: look at the same table at the and of this source from kaggle, there is the same code like in me, and it works there: https://www.kaggle.com/neisha/heart-disease-prediction-using-logistic-regression